# Progamação VBA para Inserir senha de planilha para atualizar informações

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Ótimo dia pessoal!
Tenho uma planilha matriz onde puxa as informações de outras quatro planilhas. Essas quatro planilhas são protegidas por senha. Criei um código VBA para quando abrir a planilha matriz ele já informe a senha das planilhas para atualizar as informações porém não está dando certo. Quando abro a planilha matriz ele não atualiza e a linha do ActiveWorkBook.UpdateLink fica amarela. Segue o código:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.SendKeys ("92{ENTER}")
 ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="file:///P:Alcance\Planilha de Ponto\PLANILHA DE PONTO 2021\RAFAELA COMERCIAL.xlsx", Type:=_xlExcelLinks
 
 Application.SendKeys ("92{ENTER}")
 ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="file:///P:Alcance\Planilha de Ponto\PLANILHA DE PONTO 2021\LUIZ FINANCEIRO.xlsx", Type:=_xlExcelLinks

Application.SendKeys ("92{ENTER}")
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="file:///P:Alcance\Planilha de Ponto\PLANILHA DE PONTO 2021\MARCO CONTABILIDADE.xlsx", Type:=_xlExcelLinks
```

Application.SendKeys ("92{ENTER}")
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="file:///P:Alcance\Planilha de Ponto\PLANILHA DE PONTO 2021\RENATA FISCAL.xlsx", Type:=_xlExcelLinks

SendKeys "{esc}, True

End Sub

Comment: Você já tentou rodar esse código passo a passo (apertando F8 na janela de código) para ver onde é o erro?

Comment: Em que momento o seu código insere senha? Não vejo nada disso!